# Computer stuck on fluid baking

Tags: baking, fluid-simulation, memory-management

I am trying to bake a fluid simulation of 1.45GB and my pc is stuck and stopped responding. What can I do? Will it help to increase my RAM amount to 16GB?

System specs:

- Windows 10 Pro Insider Preview 64-bit
- CPU - Intel Core i7 4770 @ 3.40GHz39 °C , Haswell 22nm Technology
- RAM - 8.00GB Dual-Channel DDR3 @ 798MHz (11-11-11-28)
- Motherboard - Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd. H81M-S2PV (SOCKET 0) 28 °C
- Graphics:

  - L1953TR (1280x1024@60Hz)
  - W2242 (1680x1050@60Hz)
  - SyncMaster (1280x1024@60Hz)
  - Intel HD Graphics 4600 (Gigabyte)
  - 2047MB NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 (MSI) 33 °C
- Storage:

  - 111GB Corsair Force LS SSD (SSD)    30 °C
  - 931GB TOSHIBA DT01ACA100 (SATA) 34 °C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OMG 1.45 GB.Dude that's quite huge than what your machine could handle smoothly.That's the problem.Try decreasing the resolution of fluid.What exactly are you doing? Not trying to simulate an ocean or huge lake :-p .16 Gb probably won't handle that huge fluid smoothly either.Try to decrease the fluid size.

Comment: I don't understand why 16GB is not enough, why 1.45GB RAM is not enough?

Comment: Because 1.45 GB of fluid simply means way too high number of vertices to handle for a computer even with 16Gb RAM.Don't believe me go ahead and select your domain and take a look at the top right hand side for vertices.You probably have close to a million vertices.

Comment: Thanks, I need to upload it to sheepit(render farm) and the size limit is 500MB, so I decrease the size to 400MB. It's work smoothly now.

Comment: yeah that's perfect size for your computer.smooth sailing man :)